# How to add the OnClickListener Object in Android?

Tags: android, button, view, onclicklistener, android-inflate

I am going through an error. Not able to add the OnClickListener object. This is following code.

```
    @Override

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {


        Activity act;

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.abc, container, false);

        TextView tt=(TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txt);

        Button button=(Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn1);


        button.setOnClickListener(mFan); // Here i am getting the error //

        View.OnClickListener mFan = new OnClickListener() 
        {

            public void onClick(View v) 
            {


            }

        };

   }
```

I am facing error in mFan OnClickListener object ,

I am getting an error of **mFan cannot be resolved to a variable**

So, please help me out , suggest me with some good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you have to create the listener,

```
View.OnClickListener mFan = new OnClickListener(){
     public void onClick(View v) 
     {
     }
};
```

and then that you have created an `OnClickListener` now set to your `button`.

```
button.setOnClickListener(mFan);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , but your second option works absolutely correct. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

You need to declare your `OnClickListener` *before* you reference it...

```
View.OnClickListener mFan = new OnClickListener() 
{
     public void onClick(View v) 
     {
         // stuff
     }
};

button.setOnClickListener(mFan);
```

You also need your `onCreateView` method to return a `View`, so don't forget:

```
return rootView;
```

at the bottom of your `onCreateView` method...

As a side note, you can accomplish the same thing using an *anonymous* listener like this:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // your stuff       
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes you mean OnClickListener mFan; but this also i am getting the error.